# IE9 compatiblity mode doesn't work

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible

I have an iFrame in my code and calling a page in this iFrame. The page contains a video player which is stored in my `public_html/video folder`.

This page on it's own runs perfectly. When it calls into the iframe in IE9, I am getting a blank white page...

I used many types of X-UA, but nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The page is rendered according to the topmost frame (the browser mode is set only once at the beginning and all values in nested frames are being ignored).